# different gateway subnet on ubuntu makes network unreachable

Tags: networking, netplan, gateway

**Edit**: The VM was moved from one hyper-v to another. In the first hyper-v it had a different IP, Mask and Gateway, and it worked.
Then I moved it to the new hyper-v and changed the network details.
I used a static MAC address also provided by the cloud provider.

I have assigned them info to `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`
Then executed `netplan apply`
However network is unreachable.
Is there any posibiliy to let ubuntu allow different subnet for the gateway?

**Edit** to provide the 50-cloud-init.yaml config file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp: no
      addresses:
        - IP/MASK
      gateway4: GATEWAY_IP
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

It's strange that route -s doesn't output any route at all:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway    Genmask    Flags Metric Ref  Use  Iface
```

Comment: Please post your full netplan config in the question.

Comment: edited: more details provided, including the network config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [netplan](https://netplan.io/examples) docummentation, I managed to make it work by using routes and on-link features.
After applying the following, it works:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp: no
      addresses:
        - IP/32
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: <GATEWAY_IP>
          on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Comment: Yes, I expected `on-link` would be the piece that was missing from your config.  Note that the `gateway4` here is redundant and broken, you should omit it in favor of the `routes:` section.

Comment: True, I have removed the gateway4: field, since we have it in the routes section too. thank you!